# Citing a citation from a paper?

Tags: publications, citations, plagiarism

So, I have a sentence in a paper I'm writing that looks like this:

> This result was first discovered by Person X (PaperX 1915).

The issue is, the paper I cite, let's call it Paper X, written by Person X, is in German, and I have not read it. I know that the result is there, because another paper, let's say Paper Y, also cited Paper X and stated that this result was there.

Do I need to cite Paper Y as well as Paper X, since it is where I found the citation and the result? Or is this not necessary, as the information which I am repeating from Paper Y is information that they themselves repeat from Paper X, which I cite?

Comment: I would try to check if the reference you found is appropriate and then cite the original paper X. You could ask a german speaker colleague or find out by formula and figures. ...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is a format for this.  See http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/cite-another-source.aspx

Comment: Please don't rely on the contents of a link for your answer - summarise the key points in the body of your answer as well.